# Presentations: Intellij/Cipboard macro at human typable speed

Tags: intellij-idea, clipboard, presentation

I'm doing a presentation which much of it involves me coding with a keyboard I was hoping in order for clarity and to reduce potential error, it could be possible not have to retype some complex sections but have them 'typed' for me at a readable speed so that I can still talk over when it is being outputted.

Looking at intellij's macro it would work perfect except it run too fast for me to talk over, is there any other tools that you know of that could assist in this?

Thanks,

Ian.

Answer (score 0):

Some people create ad-hoc live templates for their presentation that insert the whole code snippets for them. It's not human speed though.

You could try to create a small plugin with a single action which does Thread.sleep(...) synchronously and invoke it in your macros to slow them down. It's a bit tedious though.

You can split your live templates or macros in small chunks and comment after invoking each of them. This should add some continuity to the presentation and not let your listeners lose the focus.